# CGI to check available Perl version and modules

Tags: perl, deployment, dependencies, cgi, web-hosting

I am about to write a Perl CGI script that is to be deployed on a host that does not allow shell access. You interact with them through their web interface where you can upload files to the web server, including Perl CGI.

Before I start I would like to check which version of Perl is installed, and if certain CPAN modules are available. I could write my own "probe.cgi" to do that, but maybe someone already made such a tool.

Is there a CGI that runs with possibly really old versions of Perl, that you can just drop into any web server and that produces a report about the capabilities of the hosting provider being used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[list installed modules](https://metacpan.org/search?q=cgi%20list%20installed%20modules) -> [App::Module::Lister](https://metacpan.org/module/App%3a%3aModule%3a%3aLister) *This is a program to list all of the Perl modules it finds in @INC for a no-shell web hosting account*